# Random value at time of output

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, c++17

[image: what is the extra value at the output terminal]

I have written this recursive function in C++ that prints array elements, but when I run it I get an extra number as output like 634, 389, etc. Can someone please tell me why this is happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Please do **not** post images of code, edit your question to include a [mre] as **text**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first call to your function prints out arr[5] to which you didn't assign value so it takes the random value that is in that place in the memory. To fix your issue I would recommend calling function with array size - 1 so in your case

```cpp
func(arr, 4);
```

Comment: Oh, yea that makes sense, as indexing starts from 0. thankyou soo much for your help :)